# R `summary` function closest equivalent in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there any kind of helper to find the min, max (and ideally standard deviation) of each dimension in a multidimensional array within numpy? I'm looking for something like the `summary()` function in R.

My data is essentially a huge 2D array (list of lists), in which the sublists contain n dimensional values. E.g. currently I have data with 3 dimensional attributes x,y,z:

```
a = np.random.rand(100,3)
```

For each of those dimensions (x,y,z) I want to know the min, max, mean, and std.

I know one can loop through the axes and measure these values, e.g.:

```
for i in range(a.shape[-1]):
  vals = a[:,i]
  print(np.min(vals), np.max(vals), np.std(vals))
```

I find myself writing the code to do that almost every time I have a new dataset. Any way to expedite this operation would be hugely helpful!

Comment: `scipy.stats` hasa a `describe` function: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.describe.html#scipy.stats.describe

Comment: If you have to do it all the time, why not write your own function/library and import it to your project?

Comment: You can easily take the `mean` (or other measure) across rows or down columns of that 2d array.  Is that what want?

Comment: similar to @hpaulj, I would suggest pandas. It has also a describe function. Example usage ```import pandas as pd; pd.DataFrame(a).describe()```, it also gives you quantiles.

Comment: I added a little sample snippet to show what I'm doing. @QuangHoang this is the kind of thing that's juuuust too small to have warranted a library so far; I only thought I'd ask out of curiosity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without pandas:

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(100,3)
summary = stats.describe(a, axis = 0)

print(summary.mean)
print(summary.minmax)
...
```

---

Using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

summary_across_rows = pd.DataFrame(a).describe() # across axis=0
print(summary)
                0           1           2
count  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000
mean     0.495204    0.573827    0.476202
std      0.275131    0.246189    0.271626
min      0.005202    0.037195    0.023595
25%      0.295210    0.399358    0.258712
50%      0.512023    0.562181    0.417322
75%      0.710216    0.790970    0.712047
max      0.998371    0.997717    0.980840

Note: for the summary across the other dimension you need:
summary_across_columns = pd.DataFrame(a.T).describe() # across axis=1
```

Comment: this looks great! Thanks for showing the behavior of both libraries!

Comment: glad that I could help. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Without pandas:

```
from scipy import stats

stats.describe(lst)
stats.scoreatpercentile(lst,(5,10,50,90,95))
```

Here is an example:

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

stdev = 10
mu =  10
a=stdev*np.random.randn(100)+mu
stats.describe(a)
```

```
[OUT1]: DescribeResult(nobs=100, minmax=(-13.180682481878286, 40.6109521437826), mean=10.352380786199149, variance=103.27168865119998, skewness=0.13852516641657087, kurtosis=0.2691915766145532)
```

```
stats.scoreatpercentile(a,(5,10,50,90,95))
```

```
[OUT2]: array([-7.21731609, -3.22696662, 10.39364637, 21.78527621, 24.20685179])
```